# How to output a single file for each row of an excel file read in?

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2010

How can I output a file for each row of excel data? Right now it outputs the correct number of files but has the rows of data incremented, so file 1 is correct, file 2 has row 1 and row 2, etc.

```
 Dim smNum As Integer = 0

        If rowct > 0 Then

            For rr As Integer = 10 To rowct
                For cc As Integer = 1 To colct
                    val = CType(r.Cells(rr, cc), Excel.Range).Value

                    If val = "" Then Exit For

                    str.Append(ht((cc - 1).ToString)).Append(",")
                    str.Append(val)

                    'assigning the sample managaer num in column 1
                    If cc = 1 Then
                        smNum = val
                        file_name = selectedFile.Substring(13, 16) & "_" & smNum & "_" & todays_date & file_count & ".csv"
                        full_path = save_file_path & file_name
                        MessageBox.Show("Sample Manager Number: " & val & full_path)
                    End If

                    If cc < colct Then
                        str.Append(",")
                    End If

                    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(full_path, str.ToString, False)
                    lstFileOut.Items.Add(file_name)

                Next
                'str.AppendLine()
            Next

        End If
```

Comment: reinitialize your stringbuilder just inside the `For rr` loop so it doesnt accumulate more than one row of data

Comment: @Plutonix I knew it was going to be something small like that, I had been looking at it for too long. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: you should move the `WriteAllText` and `lstFileOut.Add` lines to outside the column loop (to where `str.AppendLine` is commented out).  These only need to run once per row too.  Then, you should upvote @the_lotus answer for noticing that

Comment: @Plutonix I did move the `WriteAllText` and `lstFiteOut.Add` outside the column loop. Makes sense to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [StringBuilder.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) before each row.

```
        For rr As Integer = 10 To rowct
            str.Clear()

            For cc As Integer = 1 To colct
```

I would also suggest calling My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText once per row since you are writing to the file on each columns.

Comment: Yea...how does the writer not duplicate row data given where it is?

Comment: @Plutonix the 3rd parameter is set to [append] false, every write will overwrite the whole file. Pretty useless... But lstFileOut will contain a lot of duplicate.

Comment: @the_lotus So the last row is not getting written to a file, the file is just blank, any idea why that is happening?

Comment: @0723kas have you tried putting a breakpoint? maybe rowct is off by one

Comment: @the_lotus I set a breakpoint and stepped thru the entire file manually and it outputted the last file correctly. I'm new to VB programming so I don't know where to go from here.